# Deployment using CI does not work (for GitHub at least)

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Deploying using Deployment option is not working. Step to reproduce:

1. Create a C# Azure Function project
2. Commit project to GitHub.
3. Create a new Azure Function using the "from source code" option, point out the repo, branch etc
4. The repo get pulled in successfully
5. Using Kudu, I can verify the code gets deployed
6. Function does not show up in the list of function

If I first deploy the function from VS, and later enable CI, it all works but the it seems the code does not get compiled, and the previous version (deployed from VS) is still running...

Comment: Are there any logs generated from the build step in the portal that are in error? I'm deploying from GitHub just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the scenario of git deploying a function app is not yet supported. We are working on enabling it, but don't have an ETA yet.

Comment: The recommended workaround right now is to use a build server such as VSTS to build the project.